# How are positions of sensors represented in GTSAM?

Tags: slam, gtsam

I have been reading GTSAM documentation and I'm confused on how the positions of sensors are taken into account.

Ex I have a base_link and a set of 5 sensors, 1 IMU and 4 Stereo Cameras and I have transforms between the base_link and each of them.

How do I supply these constraints?